# On Startup this message pops up : "how do you want to open this .vbs file"

Tags: windows, boot, vbscript

I got my laptop back from a friend who might have put a vb script to prank to me or something I deleted the script right away, but now **how do you want to open this .vbs file** message pops up every time I startup.

How can stop I this ?

[image]

Comment: does it appear in your startup applications in Task Manager?

Comment: We need more information - what have you tried? Have you checked startup apps? Have you checked the startup apps folder? Have you checked your registry?

Answer (score 3):

Download and use the [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) tool from Microsoft.  This tool will display all the programs, scripts, services, etc that are trying to run at start up.

Comment: This is the ONLY answer you should be reading.  Be sure to run it as an administrator.  There is nowhere that this program can access that you can't see by hand.. but it is all wrapped up in one application.

Comment: This tool is great. I had it and forgot about it. In my case, there was a path with spaces in it that needed to be wrapped with `"`. It was actually a SysInternals program!! Before it was `W:\Apps (Portable)\Screen Capture Apps\ZoomIt.exe`. Then wrapping the path with `"` to become `"W:\Apps (Portable)\Screen Capture Apps\ZoomIt.exe"` fixed it. Finding that without this tool would be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this batch file in order to give you a scan report of running :

**Processes**, **Services**, **Tasks** and **startup items**.

---

Copy and paste this code below in your notepad or notepad++ and save it as :

***[Processes_Services_Tasks_Startup.bat](https://pastebin.com/ZvWS1XL6)***

---

```bat
<# : Batch portion
@rem # The previous line does nothing in Batch, but begins a multiline comment block
@rem # in PowerShell.  This allows a single script to be executed by both interpreters.
@echo off
cls & color 9E & Mode 95,5
Title Running Processes - Scheduled Tasks - Services - Startup items by Hackoo 2020
If [%1] NEQ [Admin] Goto RunAsAdmin

echo(
echo(                ===========================================================
echo(                    Please wait a while ... Working is in progress....
echo(                ===========================================================

Set "Filter_Ext=%Temp%\Filter_Ext"
Call :GetFileNameWithDateTime MyDate
Set "Log=%~dpn0_%Computername%_%MyDate%.txt"
Set "Lnk_Target_Path_Log=%~dp0Lnk_Target_Path_Log.txt"
Set "All_Users=%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
Set "Current_User=%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
set "Winlogonkey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
Set "ImageFileExec_Key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options"
Set StartupFolders="%All_Users%" "%Current_User%"
If Exist "%Log%" Del "%Log%"
Set "VbsFile=%Tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Call :Generate_VBS_File

  Powershell ^
  Get-WmiObject Win32_Process ^
| where commandline -NE $null ^
| Select-Object ProcessID,Name,CommandLine ^
| Out-String -Width 450 ^
| Findstr /I /V "Admin" ^
| Findstr /I /V "Get-WmiObject" ^
| Out-File "%Log%" -Encoding  ASCII 

  Powershell ^
  Get-CimInstance Win32_StartupCommand ^
| Select-Object Name,command,Location,user ^
| Format-List ^
| Out-File -Append "%Log%" -Encoding  ASCII

>"%Lnk_Target_Path_Log%" (
    @For %%A in (%StartupFolders%) Do (
        Call :Execute_VBS_File "%%~A"
    )
)

>> "%Log%" (Type "%Lnk_Target_Path_Log%")

> "%Filter_Ext%" (
    echo .vbs
    echo .vbe
    echo .js
    echo .jse
    echo .bat
    echo .cmd
    echo .ps1
)

@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%Lnk_Target_Path_Log%" ^| Findstr /I /G:"%Filter_Ext%"') do (
    @for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
        >> "%Log%" 2>&1 (
            echo(
            echo ===================================================================================
            echo( Source code of TargetPath=%%b
            echo ===================================================================================
            Type %%b
        )
    )
)

Del "%Filter_Ext%" /F >nul 2>&1
Del "%Lnk_Target_Path_Log%" >nul 2>&1
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>> "%Log%" (
    echo(
    echo ****************************************************************************************************
    echo(                                 No Microsoft Scheduled Tasks List
    echo ****************************************************************************************************
    @for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0}|out-string)"') do echo %%I
    REM @For /F "tokens=2,9,17,19,20,21,22 delims=," %%a in ('SCHTASKS /Query /NH /FO CSV /V ^|find /I /V "Microsoft" ^|findstr /I /C:"VBS" /C:"EXE"') do (
    REM Set TaskName=%%~a
    REM Set TaskPath=%%~b
    REM Call :Trim_Dequote !TaskName! TaskName
    REM Call :Trim_Dequote !TaskPath! TaskPath
    REM echo "!TaskName!"
    REM echo "!TaskPath!"
    REM echo %%c;%%d;%%f;%%g
    REM echo( ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    REM )
)

>> "%Log%" (
    echo(
    echo ****************************************************************************************************
    echo(                                 No Microsoft Services List
    echo ****************************************************************************************************
@for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
    'WMIC service where "Not PathName like '%%Micro%%' AND Not PathName like '%%Windows%%'" get Name^,DisplayName^,PathName^,Status'
    ) do (
        @for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
            echo %%b
            )
    )
)

>> "%Log%" (
    echo(
    echo ****************************************************************************************************
    echo %Winlogonkey%
    Reg Query "%Winlogonkey%" | find /I "userinit"
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Reg Query "%ImageFileExec_Key%" /f "*.exe" ^|findstr /I /V ":"') do (
        @for /f "delims=" %%b in ('Reg Query "%%~a" /s /f "Debugger" ^|findstr /I /V "0" ^|findstr /I /V "1"') do (
            echo %%b
        )
    )
)

Call :ExtractCmdLine_Hashes
If Exist "%Log%" Start /MAX "Log" "%Log%" & Exit 
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Trim_Dequote <Var> <NewVar>
(
    echo    Wscript.echo Trim_Dequote("%~1"^)
    echo    Function Trim_Dequote(S^)
    echo    If Left(S, 1^) = """" And Right(S, 1^) = """" Then Trim_Dequote = Trim(Mid(S, 2, Len(S^) - 2^)^) Else Trim_Dequote = Trim(S^)
    echo    End Function
)>"%VbsFile%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Cscript //nologo "%VbsFile%"') do ( 
    set "%2=%%a" 
)
Del "%VbsFile%" /F >nul 2>&1
exit /b
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetFileNameWithDateTime <FileName>
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set "MyDate=%%x"
set "%1=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%-%MyDate:~8,2%-%MyDate:~10,2%"
Exit /B
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Generate_VBS_File
>"%VbsFile%" ( 
    echo    Option Explicit
    echo    Dim Ws,objStartFolder,objFSO,objFolder,colFiles
    echo    Dim objFile,strFilePath,Lnk,Title
    echo    Title = "Extracting Target Path from .lnk and .url files by Hackoo 2020"
    echo    Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell"^)
    echo    If WSH.Arguments.Count = 0 Then MsgBox "Missing Arguments",vbExclamation,Title : Wscript.Quit(1^)
    echo    objStartFolder = WSH.Arguments(0^)
    echo    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
    echo    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder^)
    echo    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    echo    For Each objFile in colFiles
    echo    strFilePath = objFile.Path
    echo      If Ucase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFilePath^)^) = "LNK"_
    echo       Or Ucase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(strFilePath^)^) = "URL" Then
    echo          Call ExtractTargetPath(strFilePath^)
    echo      End If
    echo    Next
    echo    '-------------------------------------------------------------
    echo    Sub ExtractTargetPath(Lnk^)
    echo    set Lnk = Ws.Createshortcut(Lnk^)
    echo    WScript.echo "Link="^& DblQuote(Lnk^) ^& vbcrlf ^&_
    echo    "Target="^& DblQuote(Lnk.TargetPath^) ^& vbcrlf ^&_
    echo    String(100,"-"^)
    echo    End Sub
    echo    '-------------------------------------------------------------
    echo    Function DblQuote(Str^)
    echo        DblQuote = Chr(34^) ^& Str ^& Chr(34^)
    echo    End Function
    echo    '-------------------------------------------------------------
)
Exit /B
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Execute_VBS_File
cscript //nologo "%VbsFile%" "%~1"
Exit /B
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:RunAsAdmin
cls & color 9E & Mode 95,5
echo(
echo(               ===========================================================
echo(                    Please wait a while ... Running as Admin ....
echo(               ===========================================================
Powershell start -verb runas '%0' Admin & Exit
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:ExtractCmdLine_Hashes
Rem Killing all Process that have a status not responding
Taskkill /f /fi "status eq not responding">nul 2>&1
Set "LogScan=%~dp0Log_Scan"
If Not Exist %LogScan%\ MD %LogScan%
Set "Abs_cmdline=%LogScan%\%~n0_Abs_cmdline.txt"
Set "Tmp_cmdline=%LogScan%\%~n0_Tmp_cmdline.txt
Set "cmdline=%LogScan%\%~n0_cmdline.txt
Set "TmpHashes=%LogScan%\%~n0_TmpHashes.txt"
Set "Hashes=%LogScan%\%~n0_Hashes.txt"
Set "Hash2Check_VirusTotal=%LogScan%\Hash2Check_VirusTotal.txt"
For %%a in ("%Abs_cmdline%" "%Tmp_cmdline%" "%TmpHashes%" "%Hash2Check_VirusTotal%") Do If Exist "%%a" Del "%%a"
Set ProcessNames="wscript.exe" "cmd.exe" "powershell.exe" "cscript.exe" "svchost.exe"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (%ProcessNames%) Do (
    REM echo(
    REM echo Please Wait a while ... Looking for any instance of %%A ...
    Call :GetCommandLine %%A>nul 2>&1 
)
Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
Call :Extract "%Abs_cmdline%" "%Tmp_cmdline%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%Tmp_cmdline%"') do (
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%H in ('CertUtil -hashfile "%%~a" SHA256 ^| findstr /i /v "CertUtil"') do set "H=%%H"
        REM echo %%a=!H: =!
        echo %%a=!H: =! >> "%TmpHashes%"
)

Call :RemoveDuplicateEntry %TmpHashes% %Hashes%
Call :RemoveDuplicateEntry %Tmp_cmdline% %cmdline%
If exist "%TmpHashes%" Del "%TmpHashes%" & If exist "%Tmp_cmdline%" Del "%Tmp_cmdline%"

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('Type "%Hashes%"') do (
    If /I "%%~xa"==".vbs" MD %LogScan%\VBS>nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\VBS\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".vbe" MD %LogScan%\VBE>nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\VBE\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".js"  MD %LogScan%\JS>nul  2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\JS\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".jse" MD %LogScan%\JSE>nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\JSE\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".bat" MD %LogScan%\BAT>nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\BAT\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".cmd" MD %LogScan%\CMD>nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\CMD\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".ps1" MD %LogScan%\PS1>nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\PS1\%%~nxa.txt"
    If /I "%%~xa"==".wsf" MD %LogScan%\WSF>nul 2>&1 & Type "%%a" > "%LogScan%\WSF\%%~nxa.txt"
    Set "Hash=%%b"
    Set "Hash=!Hash: =!
    IF {!Hash!} NEQ {!CMD_HASH!} (
        IF {!Hash!} NEQ {!PS_HASH!} (
            echo https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/%%b>>"%Hash2Check_VirusTotal%"
            Start "Chek SHA256 on VIRUSTOTAL" "https://www.virustotal.com/old-browsers/file/%%b"
        )
    )
)
::Start "" /MAX "%Hashes%" 
::Start "" /MAX "%cmdline%"
Exit /B
::********************************************************************************************************
:GetCommandLine <ProcessName>
Set "ProcessCmd="
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%P in ('wmic process where caption^="%~1" get commandline /format:list ^| findstr /I "%~1" ^| find /I /V "%~nx0" 2^>nul') do (
    Set "ProcessCmd=%%P"
    REM echo !ProcessCmd!
    echo !ProcessCmd! >> "%Abs_cmdline%"
)
Exit /b
::********************************************************************************************************
:Extract <InputData> <OutPutData>
(
echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
echo Data = Extract(Data,"(^?^!.*(\x22\w\W^)^).*(\.ps1^|\.vbs^|\.vbe^|\.js^|\.jse^|\.cmd^|\.bat^|\.wsf^|\.exe^)(^?^!.*(\x22\w\W^)^)"^)
echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Data
echo Function Extract(Data,Pattern^)
echo    Dim oRE,oMatches,Match,Line
echo    set oRE = New RegExp
echo    oRE.IgnoreCase = True
echo    oRE.Global = True
echo    oRE.Pattern = Pattern
echo    set oMatches = oRE.Execute(Data^)
echo    If not isEmpty(oMatches^) then
echo        For Each Match in oMatches  
echo            Line = Line ^& Trim(Match.Value^) ^& vbcrlf
echo        Next
echo        Extract = Line 
echo    End if
echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::****************************************************
::----------------------------------------------------
:RemoveDuplicateEntry <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
Powershell  ^
$Contents=Get-Content '%1';  ^
$LowerContents=$Contents.ToLower(^);  ^
$LowerContents ^| select -unique ^| Out-File '%2'
Exit /b
::----------------------------------------------------
: end Batch / begin PowerShell hybrid code #>
Function getTasks($path) {
    $out = @()
    # Get root tasks
    $schedule.GetFolder($path).GetTasks(0) | % {
        $xml = [xml]$_.xml
        $out += New-Object psobject -Property @{
            "Name" = $_.Name
            "Path" = $_.Path
            "LastRunTime" = $_.LastRunTime
            "NextRunTime" = $_.NextRunTime
            "Actions" = ($xml.Task.Actions.Exec | % { "$($_.Command) $($_.Arguments)" }) -join "`n"
"==============" = "===================================================================================="
        }
    }
    # Get tasks from subfolders
    $schedule.GetFolder($path).GetFolders(0) | % {
        $out += getTasks($_.Path)
    }
    #Output
    $out
}
$tasks = @()
$schedule = New-Object -ComObject "Schedule.Service"
$schedule.Connect() 
# Start inventory
$tasks += getTasks("\")
# Close com
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($schedule) | Out-Null
Remove-Variable schedule

# To show All No Microsoft Scheduled Tasks
$tasks | ? { $_.Path -notmatch "Micro*" } | Out-String -Width 450
```